# Shortcut commenting on internal CSS in VSCode

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, shortcut

I try to comment a line in internal CSS in HTML file (in style element) using `Ctrl + /` but VSCode comment the line like html (using `<!--  -->`)
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNFEI.png)

I know I should use `/*  */` but I want to know how can I comment a line in internal CSS using VSCode shortcut?

Note: I use Version: 1.60.2 (user setup) and these are [my extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKGlS.png).

Comment: It works fine on my machine. Commenting out declarations in a style block will comment out correctly. I don't have any extensions installed that would change this behaviour. Are you on the newest version, and what language is set in the bottom right? Make sure it's HTML, not XML.

Comment: Version: 1.60.2 (user setup)
and yeah it is HTML in the bottom right.

Answer (score 4):

The alternative shortcut to comment code is <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, and for uncommenting it's <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd>.

For some languages, CSS for example, <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> work as toggle for both states.

Comment: Ctrl+K+C, Ctrl+K+U and Ctrl+/ are exactly works like each other in this case (for me).

Comment: It's normal that's the case in CSS. but not with php and sql, for exemple.

Comment: but I see this property in tutorial that I use to learn CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in vs code:

`Settings > keyboard shortcuts > Emmet Toggle Comment`

It will be set to the default source
Add a key binding to it, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The default shortcut in Windows is Ctrl+#.

Alternatively, you can search for "Toggle comment" under File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts and enter the desired key combination.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > keyboard shortcuts > Emmet Toggle Comment

It will be set to the default source Add a key binding to it, and it will work.